# why $("#id").addclass jquery not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

My knowledge about jquery has just begun.
Below code works in IE11 but not in IE9.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id='panel'></div>
    </body>
</html>    
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadData();    
});

function loaddata(){
var div = document.createElement('div');

var str='<div id="dummy" onclick="slideOut(this.id);">Click Here</div>'

div.innerHTML = str;

        document.getElementById("panel").appendChild(div);
}

function slideOut(temp){

$("'#'"+temp+"'").addclass("hidden");
}
```

slideOut is called but it is not adding hidden class to the div.
I think this is something with $(document) instead of $("#id"). Above code is working well in IE11 but not in IE9 (emulate in debugger).
Any help please.

Comment: try to provide jsfiddle for the same..

Comment: @devendra i trying to create one ll post one in sometime.

Comment: @Fergoso still problem is there.

Comment: Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/shailendra_baranwal/3he55hx8/3/

Comment: updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/shailendra_baranwal/3he55hx8/7/

Comment: your fiddle does not work in chrome either?

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/3he55hx8/8/

Comment: did my fiddle work for you @ShailendraBaranwal?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is case sensitive. `addClass` is the proper method name, the 'c' should be uppercase.

Try

```
$("#" + temp).addClass("hidden");
```

You have your jsFiddle set to onDomReady, which means you don't need the redundant `$(document).ready()` statement. You can set it to `no wrap in <body>` to get it working.

Also, jQuery has a helper method called `.hide()` so you don't need to attach a hidden CSS class. `$("#" + temp).hide()` would also work.

Here is a [working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3he55hx8/12/) of your example.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
var str='<div id="dummy" onclick="slideOut(this.id);return false;">Click Here</div>'
```

also

```
$('#'+temp).addClass('hidden');
```